# Pass Value from ListView To EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, android-edittext

I get an activity which one has 3 Clickables EditTexts which are 3 differents Searchables ListViews with MatchCode by ButtonClick starts a new activity

but when i get for example the first value(1° EditText) on ListView it appears in the EditText(MainActivity) how is expected and when i call the 2nd and 3rd EditText which one are other clickable and get the values, erase all the others EditTexts in the activity any ideas why this is happenning ??

I know that i might need to treat the actions with an intent to set and get the values, but i'm in trouble with that so i'm posting the code and the photo to let you guys help me,

probably its some simple solution that i don't know or with i'm not able to do that, tell me how can i get a solution for that...

Here is a photo with whats is happening:

[image]

And here is my code in my main activity

```
public class Formulario_ItemNota extends Formulario_Nota {
private ListView listaProblemas;
private ItemNota_Helper itemnota_helper;
private List<ItemNota> itemnotas;
private ItemNota itemnotaSelecionado;
private Intent int_conjunto;
private Intent int_problema;

private EditText ETconjunto;
private EditText ETproblema;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Daniel: onCreate" + new Date());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_itemnota);

    this.itemnota_helper = new ItemNota_Helper(this);

    ETconjunto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_conjunto);
    ETconjunto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent material = new Intent(Formulario_ItemNota.this, ListaMateriais.class);
            startActivity(material);
        }
    });

    ETproblema = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_problemas);
    ETproblema.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent problema = new Intent(Formulario_ItemNota.this, ListaProblemas.class);
            startActivity(problema);
        }
    });

    final EditText ETprocedencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_procedencia);
    ETprocedencia.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent procedencia = new Intent(Formulario_ItemNota.this, ListaProcedencia.class);
            startActivity(procedencia);
        }
    });

    Intent int_conjunto = getIntent();
    String tEXT_conjunto = int_conjunto.getStringExtra("TextMateriais");
    EditText et_conj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_conjunto);
    System.out.println("conjunto: " + et_conj);
    ETconjunto.setText(tEXT_conjunto, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    Intent int_problema = getIntent();
    String tEXT_problema = int_problema.getStringExtra("TextProblemas");
    EditText et_problema = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_problemas);
    System.out.println("problema: " + et_problema);
    ETproblema.setText(tEXT_problema, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    Intent int_procedencia = getIntent();
    String tEXT_procedencia = int_procedencia.getStringExtra("TextProcedencia");
    EditText et_procedencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_procedencia);
    et_procedencia.setText(tEXT_procedencia, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    Stara_DB ItemNotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_ItemNota.this);
    itemnotas = ItemNotaDao.getListaIN();
    ItemNotaDao.close();

    ArrayAdapter<ItemNota> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemNota>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemnotas);
    listaProblemas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_descr_problemas);
    listaProblemas.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listaProblemas);

}

private void carregaListaItemNota() {
    Stara_DB ItemNotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_ItemNota.this);
    List<ItemNota> itensnotas = ItemNotaDao.getListaIN();
    ItemNotaDao.close();

    ArrayAdapter<ItemNota> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemNota>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itensnotas);
    this.listaProblemas.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menuItem, View vItem, ContextMenuInfo menuInfoItem) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menuItem, vItem, menuInfoItem);
    listaProblemas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_descr_problemas);
    MenuItem editar = menuItem.add("Editar");
    editar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    MenuItem deletar = menuItem.add("Deletar");
    deletar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item1) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Formulario_ItemNota.this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Deletar").setMessage("Deseja mesmo deletar ?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Stara_DB ItemNotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_ItemNota.this);
                            ItemNotaDao.deletar(itemnotaSelecionado);
                            ItemNotaDao.close();
                            carregaListaItemNota();
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Não", null).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.itemnotamenu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.addItem:
        ItemNota itemnota = itemnota_helper.pegaItemNotaDoFormulario();

        Stara_DB ItemNotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_ItemNota.this);
        itemnotas = ItemNotaDao.getListaIN();
        ItemNotaDao.insereItemNota(itemnota);
        Toast.makeText(Formulario_ItemNota.this, "Dados Salvos com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        carregaListaItemNota();
        ItemNotaDao.close();
        return true;

    case R.id.CriarOrdem:
        Intent intentl = new Intent(Formulario_ItemNota.this, Formulario_OS.class);
        startActivity(intentl);
        return true;

    default:

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

And here is one of my 3 ListViews which are the same with only different values;

```
public class ListaMateriais extends Activity {

    private ListView listamateriais;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapMatchMaterial;
    EditText inputSearch;
    public EditText ETclient; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_material_match);

        String products[] = { "Parafuso 3x4 092387",
                          "Cabeçote redpo 09873", 
                          "alavanca de ignição 027625",
                          "Pistão de arranque 093298092", 
                          "Eixo dianteiro 0343232",
                          "Cabeçote parafuseta 093232" };
        listamateriais = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_match_material);
        adapMatchMaterial = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        listamateriais.setAdapter(adapMatchMaterial);

        listamateriais.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,  long arg3) {
                String text= (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("TextMateriais", text);
                Intent int_material = new Intent(ListaMateriais.this,Formulario_ItemNota.class);
                int_material.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(int_material);
                finish();
            }
        });

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.materialSearch); 
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                ListaMateriais.this.adapMatchMaterial.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Any helps will be truly appreciate !!!O

Comment: I want to help you but your wording makes it really hard to understand what the problem is and your code is a mess. It needs indents, white spaces and variables starting with small letters.

Comment: You have the MainAnctivity(which contains 3 clickable edit text) -> after click, you open one of your ListActivities to select an item -> when you come back to MainActivity you don't find the old values insered in your EditText(s)? is that your problem?

Comment: Yeah @Rami it's exactly my problem, do you know what i'm missing ?? like i thought in fragments but i'm not that good with fragment, so i find this solution, but i'm not handling well with the intents to pass the values... i'm newer in programming, so if you have a better solution just let me know or if this is simple to solve, will be even better... thanks a lot man

Comment: okay let's try to be more simple, i'm agree with you @user3427079 i'm starting to code and this is my first app, but just to let you know the fisrt example of code, is just the call of the edittext to listview, i have all the other atributes in my class, but can you be more specific in what way i need to go solve, or correct

Comment: to try be more useful my main activity its a form and in this listviews i want to get customername, problems and things like that, so i need to have a list form my db to each item(entities) to input in my form, and store my form in a nota service,  got the logic ? thats what i'm trying to do hope this will facilitate my mess xD

Comment: Can you please post your full code of the MainActivity? because i need to know when exactly you change the texts. But at first thought, i guess in each time you came back to your MainActivity you want to get "TextProblemas" and "TextMateriais" from the intent and reset your editText(s), unfortunately when you were in *ListaMateriais* for example you only set the *TextMateriais*, so when you try to get *TextProblemas* from intent it will be an empty string and as a result you erase the old value of EditText_Problemas.

Comment: Yeah @Rami i took a look at and i think is that my problem so i'm posting my main activity code here just a second...

Comment: @Rami Done, i just updated here is my class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After selecting an item from your list, you are opening another instance of Formulario_ItemNota. This is why you loose your editText data.

try this:

```
 public class Formulario_ItemNota extends Formulario_Nota {
    private ListView listaProblemas;
    private ItemNota_Helper itemnota_helper;
    private List<ItemNota> itemnotas;
    private ItemNota itemnotaSelecionado;
    private Intent int_conjunto;
    private Intent int_problema;

    private EditText ETconjunto;
    private EditText ETproblema;
    private EditText ETprocedencia;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Daniel: onCreate" + new Date());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form_itemnota);

        this.itemnota_helper = new ItemNota_Helper(this);

        ETconjunto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_conjunto);
        ETconjunto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent material = new Intent(Formulario_ItemNota.this, ListaMateriais.class);
                startActivityForResult(material, 1);
            }
        });

        ETproblema = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_problemas);
        ETproblema.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent problema = new Intent(Formulario_ItemNota.this, ListaProblemas.class);
                startActivityForResult(problema , 2);
            }
        });

        ETprocedencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_procedencia);
        ETprocedencia.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent procedencia = new Intent(Formulario_ItemNota.this, ListaProcedencia.class);
                startActivityForResult(procedencia , 3);
            }
        });

        Stara_DB ItemNotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_ItemNota.this);
        itemnotas = ItemNotaDao.getListaIN();
        ItemNotaDao.close();

        ArrayAdapter<ItemNota> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemNota>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemnotas);
        listaProblemas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_descr_problemas);
        listaProblemas.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listaProblemas);

    }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {// back from ListaMateriais.class
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String resultFromMateriais=data.getStringExtra("TextMateriais");
            ETconjunto.setText(resultFromMateriais);
        }
    } else if (requestCode == 2) { // back from ListaProblemas.class
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String resultFromProblemas=data.getStringExtra("TextProblemas");
            ETproblema.setText(resultFromProblemas);
        }
    } else if (requestCode == 3) { // back from  ListaProcedencia.class
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String resultFromProcedencia=data.getStringExtra("TextProcedencia");
            ETprocedencia.setText(resultFromProcedencia);
        }
    }
  }

    private void carregaListaItemNota() {
        Stara_DB ItemNotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_ItemNota.this);
        List<ItemNota> itensnotas = ItemNotaDao.getListaIN();
        ItemNotaDao.close();

        ArrayAdapter<ItemNota> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemNota>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itensnotas);
        this.listaProblemas.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menuItem, View vItem, ContextMenuInfo menuInfoItem) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menuItem, vItem, menuInfoItem);
        listaProblemas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_descr_problemas);
        MenuItem editar = menuItem.add("Editar");
        editar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItem deletar = menuItem.add("Deletar");
        deletar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item1) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Formulario_ItemNota.this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Deletar").setMessage("Deseja mesmo deletar ?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Stara_DB ItemNotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_ItemNota.this);
                                ItemNotaDao.deletar(itemnotaSelecionado);
                                ItemNotaDao.close();
                                carregaListaItemNota();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Não", null).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.itemnotamenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addItem:
            ItemNota itemnota = itemnota_helper.pegaItemNotaDoFormulario();

            Stara_DB ItemNotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_ItemNota.this);
            itemnotas = ItemNotaDao.getListaIN();
            ItemNotaDao.insereItemNota(itemnota);
            Toast.makeText(Formulario_ItemNota.this, "Dados Salvos com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            carregaListaItemNota();
            ItemNotaDao.close();
            return true;

        case R.id.CriarOrdem:
            Intent intentl = new Intent(Formulario_ItemNota.this, Formulario_OS.class);
            startActivity(intentl);
            return true;

        default:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

and in your 3 ListActivities, you must change them like that:

```
listamateriais.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,  long arg3) {
                String text= (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey @Rami great job, thanks a lot, thats what i was nedding, i really appreciate your helpful answer... have a nice day ;)

Comment: By the way @Rami i changed my String Adapter from a DbTable, which one are geting the data from an Odata service and i'm consuming and storing this data with the odata4j api, and when i populate my listview I again get stuck, in transfering my listView item to my edit text, still using your solution...

Comment: "i guess" the try to catch both values from my table because odata4j uses List<OEntity> to persist in the db, so when i get my intent to trasnfer the text the pop an exception to me such this ("12-08 20:30:45.577: E/AndroidRuntime(8481): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {stara.formularios/stara.formularios.views.Formulario_Nota}: java.lang.NullPointerException") i'm posting my code below

Comment: I haven't understand exactly the changes that you did. But from your logCat you have NullPointerException here, so there is an object null in your code. Check your objects in the line that cause the exception

Comment: okay @Rami i just updated my code with exactly the same code you posted here and i got the exception...

java.lang.ClassCastException: stara.modelos.ClienteModelo cannot be cast to java.lang.String

at stara.listas.dados.mestres.views.ListaDeClientes$1.onItemClick(ListaDeClientes.java:48)

In my db the files are as Text, and i have a class helper to manage the connection between the db and to populate my list view, do you have any ideas, because i don't... thanks

Comment: It's not the same question so you must post your code in another question to avoid being banned by the admins. In your last comment i see another Exception; you are trying to cast *ClienteModelo* to String. I need to see the code to know where exactly you do this.

Comment: okay so i will change my main post here okay ? i think it's better than create another code, okay, i'm just getting the logic in here i'm new using the tool...

Comment: No you need to create another question. If another user come and have the same problem (as your first question) should find his answer, otherwise he will see your second question and answers of another question(the first one).

Comment: Okay... Thanks... For the instructions